# Problems regarding multivariable calculus

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ be differentiable at $x_0\in \Omega$ ($\Omega$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R^n$), let $f(x_0)=0$ and let $g:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ be continuous at $x_0$. We want to prove that $fg:\Omega\to \mathbb R$, defined by $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$ for all $x\in \Omega$, is differential at $x_0$.

What I did is $\dfrac{\partial fg}{\partial x_i}\mid(x_0)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\mid (x_0)g(x_0)$ for each $i=1,2,...,n$. Now how to proceed?

Comment: You want to prove $fg$ is differentiable, but you're taking partial derivatives. Why? What is your definition of differentiability?

Comment: No I want to show that $\lim\limits_{\parallel h\parallel\to 0}\dfrac{fg(x_0+h)-fg(x_0)-\alpha.h}{\parallel h\parallel}=0$ where $\alpha=(\dfrac{\partial fg}{\partial x_1},...\dfrac{\partial fg}{\partial x_n})$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f(x_0) = 0$, for all sufficiently small $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we can write 
$$f(x_0+h) = u(h) + \varphi(h), \quad \text{where} \quad u(h) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_j}\cdot h_j \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\varphi(h)}{||h||} = 0.$$
Thus, for $(fg)(x_0+h)$ we have
$$ (fg)(x_0+h) = u(h)g(x_0) + \psi(h), \quad \text{where} \quad \psi(h) = u(h)\left(g(x_0+h) - g(x_0)\right) + \varphi(h)g(x_0+h).$$
In order to prove that $(fg)(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ we have to show that $\lim_{h\to 0} \psi(h)\,/\,||h|| = 0$, To this end, observe that on one hand, $g(x_0+h) - g(x_0) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, by virtue of the continuity of $g(x)$ at $x_0$, and also
$$ |u(h)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \left|\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_j}\right|\left|h_j\right| \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \left|\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_j}\right|\right)\cdot||h||, $$
which shows that $u(h)\,/\,||h||$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore,
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(h)}{||h||} \left(g(x_0+h) - g(x_0)\right) = 0.$$
On the other hand, we have
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\varphi(h)}{||h||} g(x_0+h) = \left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\varphi(h)}{||h||}\right)g(x_0) = 0.$$
Thus, $\lim_{h\to 0} \psi(h)\,/\,||h|| = 0$ and hence, $(fg)(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with total derivative
$$ g(x_0)u(h) = \sum_{j=1}^n g(x_0)\frac{\partial f(x_0)}{\partial x_j}h_j.$$